# Changing a Model's value in httppost action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm looking to change the value of a string in a view model in the controller and pass it back to the view like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestAction(TestViewModel model)
{
    model.TestStringValue = "test val";
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

The value is shown in a textbox but isn't showing the updated value. What do I need to do in the controller to update a view model's field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ModelState.Remove("TestStringValue");
model.TestStringValue = "test val";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

To Clear Model State Values

Comment: This would also work but I have other values in the model that I don't want to clear (although I realise this isn't clear in the question)